# Is there a way to put a conditional in an aws event bridge input transformer?

Tags: aws-event-bridge

Let's say something like:

```
{
  "InputPathsMap": {"instance1": "$.detail.instance1","instance2": "$.detail.instance2"},
  "InputTemplate": "<instance1 || instance2>"
}
```